# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to run a query for every number of Zip code of an area , for example
I have n number of zip code and I have to run the query for each one, I try to do it with a variable and a select , but came with this error , I can change the zip code every time and run it, but is about 300 zip code so i will spend all day on it.

This is part of my query

```
----Declare Variable

Declare @Zip1 as int

Declare @Zip2 as Int

Declare @DistanceMax as numeric

Declare @DistanceMin as Numeric

set @Zip1 = (select  distinct(zip_code)  from zipcode
Where zip_code  <>' ' )

-----@Zip1='85001'---If I do this way I have to run for every zipcode
```

I run my query depending of the value of @ZIP1
and its give me the error every time I run with the select clause

Any Clue?

Comment: The message is pretty clear.  The subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: You aren't getting a single value for `@Zip1` but SQL-Server wants only one row.

Comment: yes but I need to run for every zip code and I dont want to do it manually ?

Comment: What do you want for output? Can you show all of your query?

Comment: SELECT h.* ,(g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)/1609.344) as miles
FROM zipcodes g 
JOIN zipcodes h on g.zipcode <> h.zipcode
AND g.zipcode = @Zip1 -----You can select from one Zip Code to Another
----AND h.zipcode <= @Zip2----->= <=
WHERE g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)<=(@DistanceMax * 1609.344))-------Max Miles 5 or 10 or 15 Miles
--AND g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)>= (@DistanceMin * 1609.344))------Min Miles from the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we said in the comments:
You aren't getting a single value for @Zip1 but SQL-Server wants only one row.

Solution to that is that `@Zip1` isn't an int but a table.
Assumption `zip_code` is nvarchar:

```
DECLARE @Zip1 TABLE 
( 
 zipid NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Zip1
    SELECT distinct zip_code from zipcode
    Where zip_code  <>' '
```

You can call @Zip1 just like any other Table:

```
SELECT zipid FROM @Zip1
```

Comment: Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
Must declare the scalar variable "@Zip1".